# Convert bibtex-entries to mediawiki-syntax

Tags: converters, mediawiki, pandoc, bibtex, citations

i'm trying to convert some **Bibtex-entries** into **Mediawiki-syntax**. For example, the input is:

```
@Book{henze_layers_of_time_2000,
  author     = {Henze, Paul B.},
  location   = {London},
  publisher  = {C. Hurst \& Co. Publishers},
  title      = {Layers of Time},
  year       = {2000},
  isbn       = {9781850653936},
  subtitle   = {A History of Ethiopia},
  url        = {https://books.google.de/books?id=gzwoedwOkQMC&pg=PA54&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false},
}
```

And i want to receive the output provided by the [Wikipedia:Citation Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_templates#):

```
{{cite book
| title = Layers of Time: A History of Ethiopia
| last = Henze 
| first = Paul B. 
| year = 2000
| publisher = [[C. Hurst & Co. Publishers]]
| url = https://books.google.com/books?id=gzwoedwOkQMC&pg=PA54
| isbn = 978-1-850-65393-6
}}
```

I tried using `pandoc`:

`pandoc -s -C -f bibtex -t mediawiki  test.bib -o test.wiki`

(also with different *flags* and *options*), but either got an empty file, or a finished citation including **html** code and **mediawiki**-syntax like (here another exemplary book):

```html
<div id="refs" class="references csl-bib-body hanging-indent">
<div id="ref-Lohwasser2001" class="csl-entry">
Lohwasser, Angelika. 2001. ''Die Königlichen Frauen Im Antiken Reich von Kusch: 25. Dynastie Bis Zur Zeit Des Nastasen''. Meroitica 19. Wiesbaden: Harrassowitz Verlag.
</div>
</div>
```

I also searched Wikipedia/Mediawiki-extensions, but so far couldn't find anything fitting (I may have overlooked something, for sure). Does anybody know another possibility to convert from Bibtex into these special Mediawiki-style?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has not been implemented yet. Please raise an issue for it at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues.

If you don't want to wait for a new release, then you could consider to write a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html): The idea would be to get the citations with `pandoc.utils.references`, which returns a list of JSON-CSL-like elements. Those would then be converted to the desired output structure.

Comment: Thanks tarleb. Since its not urgent, i posted an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8801), as you supposed. For writing a filter on my own i don't have the Lua programming skills, let alone time...